# Using arbitrary number of classes

Tags: java, generics

I would appreciate any help in solving the following question.

Design and implement a subclass of GenericOrder called ComputerPartyOrder that takes an arbitrary number of different classes of ComputerPart objects, Peripheral objects, Cheese objects, Fruit objects and Service objects.

here is the code for Product class and GerericOrder class.

```
abstract class Product {
    protected float price;

    // return the price of a particular product
    abstract float price();

    //public getType() {
    //
    //}
}

//------------------------------------------------------------

class ComputerPart extends Product {
    public ComputerPart(float p) {
    price = p;
    }

    public float price() { return price; }
}

class Motherboard extends ComputerPart {
    protected String manufacturer;
    public Motherboard(String mfg, float p) {
    super(p);
    manufacturer = mfg;
    }
    public String getManufacturer() { return manufacturer; }
}

class RAM extends ComputerPart {
    protected int size;
    protected String manufacturer;
    public RAM(String mfg, int size, float p) {
    super(p);
    this.manufacturer = mfg;
    this.size = size;
    }
    public String getManufacturer() { return manufacturer; }
}

class Drive extends ComputerPart {
    protected String type;
    protected int speed;
    public Drive(String type, int speed, float p) {
    super(p);
    this.type = type;
    this.speed = speed;
    }
    public String getType() { return type; }
    public int getSpeed() { return speed; }
}


class Peripheral extends Product {
    public Peripheral(float p) {
    price = p;
    }
    public float price() { return price; }
}

class Printer extends Peripheral {
    protected String model;
    public Printer(String model, float p) {
    super(p);
    this.model = model;
    }
    public String getModel() { return model; }
}

class Monitor extends Peripheral {
    protected String model;
    public Monitor(String model, float p) {
    super(p);
    this.model = model;
    }
    public String getModel() { return model; }
}

class Service extends Product {
    public Service(float p) {
    price = p;
    }
    public float price() { return price; }
}

class AssemblyService extends Service {
    String provider;
    public AssemblyService(String pv, float p) {
    super(p);
    provider = pv;
    }
    public String getProvider() { return provider; }
}

class DeliveryService extends Service {
    String courier;
    public DeliveryService(String c, float p) {
    super(p);
    courier = c;
    }
    public String getCourier() { return courier; }
}

//-------------------------------------------------------
class Cheese extends Product {
    public Cheese(float p) {
    price = p;
    }
    public float price() { return price; }
}

class Cheddar extends Cheese {
    public Cheddar(float p) {
    super(p);
    }
}
class Mozzarella extends Cheese {
    public Mozzarella(float p) {
    super(p);
    }
}

class Fruit extends Product {
    public Fruit(float p) {
    price = p;
    }
    public float price() { return price; }
}
class Apple extends Fruit {
    public Apple(float p) {
    super(p);
    }
}
class Orange extends Fruit {
    public Orange(float p) {
    super(p);
    }
}
```

GenericOrder:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class GenericOrder<T> extends Product {
    private static long counter = 1;
    private final long id = counter++;
    private List<T> Item;

    public GenericOrder() {
        Item = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public long getid() {
        return id;
    }

    public void addItem(T newItem) {
        Item.add(newItem);
    }

    public List<T> getItem() {
        return Item;
    }

    public void setItem(List<T> Item) {
        this.Item = Item;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Code so far

```
public abstract class ComputerPartyOrder extends GenericOrder {
    GenericOrder GOrder = new GenericOrder() {
        @Override
        float price() {
            return 0;
        }
    };

    public void input(Product newitem) {
        GOrder.addItem(newitem);
    }

    public void output() {
        System.out.println(GOrder.getItem());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the specific problem you have with your homework? What have you tried and in what way it doesn't work?

Comment: @Oleg I haven't made much progress so far I got the objects needed into the ComputerPartyOrder but I can't figure out the "arbitrary number" part sorry my question wasn't that clear

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, but `GenericOrder` does not need a type parameter `T`. Instead, you can set the type of `Item` to `Product` (the superclass of all the different types of products).

```
public abstract class GenericOrder extends Product {
    private static long counter = 1;
    private final long id = counter++;
    private List<Product> Item;

    public GenericOrder() {
        Item = new ArrayList<Product>();
    }

    public long getid() {
        return id;
    }

    public void addItem(Product newItem) {
        Item.add(newItem);
    }

    public List<Product> getItem() {
        return Item;
    }

    public void setItem(List<Product> Item) {
        this.Item = Item;
    }
}
```

You will still be able to call `addItem` with any instance of a subclass of `Product`.

I would also suggest renaming `Item` to `item`, uppercase names are usually used for types, not variables.

Comment: So I won't need a method to specifically add objects with a random instance and just use `addItem()` and `getItem()` to call and then print the objects

Comment: @dxbh0517 Yup, this is because of polymorphism (more specifically, liskov substitution principle). Any instance of a subclass `Product` can be given to a method accepting `Product`.

Comment: sorry follow up question for the client class for some reason the method is not accepting any of the objects under GenericOrder. I added the code I have so far in the question incase I misunderstood what you meant earlier.

Comment: @dxbh0517 Are you talking about `ComputerPartyOrder`?

Comment: yeah i'm trying to call `Motherboard` for example but it's giving me an error and telling me to add `creat field Motherboard in ComputerPartOrder'

Comment: So I think I was suppose to use `product` as the input, not `Motherboard` so I have an output now but my output looks like this `[ComputerPartyOrderClient$2@10f87f48]` is this what it should look like?